# C++ CLI cryptic function call

Tags: c#, c++-cli, marshalling

So I'm trying to call a function that is a manged wrapper around an OCX object. Having great difficulty. Function is;

```
foo(System::Object ^% theBuffer)
```

where 'theBuffer' is an array of bytes. The template for the unmanaged OCX which 'foo' wraps is

```
goo(VARIANT* theBuffer);
```

So I've tried;

```
System::Int32 buf[10];
foo(buf);
```

which fails. And

```
Bitmap ^b;
foo(b);
```

which compiles but obviously the called function is not going to create a .NET bitmap for me.

So I guess the question is how do I pass this function a block of memory it can write to and then get access to it back in .NET world.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a documentation or example code for the OCX function? It's impossible to *guess* what parameter the function expects through the 'VARIANT *theBuffer'.

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert a `VARIANT` to the buffer directly.

First you need to check what kind of object is stored in it by checking `theBuffer->vt`. The returned value will be of the type `VARTYPE`.

Comment: sorry I phrased the question wrong, see edit. So I'm not actually trying to write the wrapper. I just need to know what to pass to foo(System::Object ^% theBuffer) given that it wraps a function that looks like goo(VARIANT* theBuffer).

Answer (score 0):

What about something like..

```
Bitmap ^b = gcnew Bitmap(...
foo(b);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the 'foo' wrapper function dosn't seem to do any sort of smart passing to the unamanged version so it has no knowledge of how to construct .NET objects. I think it basically just wants a block of memory.

Comment: From what I remember of C++/CLI, the COM wrapper are built in such a way you shouldn't worry about all that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

ok so I'm actually using the Axis Media Control SDK to interface with a network camera ( http://www.axis.com/techsup/cam_servers/dev/activex.htm ). The OCX function I am calling via the wrapper looks like;

```
HRESULT GetCurrentImage(int theFormat,    [C++]
        VARIANT* theBuffer,
        LONG* theBufferSize
       );
```

the wrapper is supplied by Axis. Using .NET Reflector I have disasembled the wrapper function;

```
public: virtual void __gc* GetCurrentImage(Int32 __gc* theFormat, [Out] Object __gc*   *theBuffer, [Out] Int32 __gc* *theBufferSize)
{
    if (this->ocx == 0)
    {
        throw __gc new InvalidActiveXStateException(S"GetCurrentImage", ActiveXInvokeKind::MethodInvoke);
    }
    this->ocx->GetCurrentImage(theFormat, out theBuffer, out theBufferSize);
}
```

So it's not doing anything smart, just passing a chunk of memory. In C++ CLI syntax the template looks like;

```
GetCurrentImage(int theFormat, System::Object ^% theBuffer, int % theBufferSize)
```

So my question becomes how do I pass this a chunk of memory to write to and then recover it back into a .NET object. I tried this;

```
unsigned char c[100];
GetCurrentImage(0, (System::Object)c, BufSize);
```

but obviously it dosn't work.